# KnockoutJS- Show message when foreach has no result

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, foreach

One of the web pages is showing products using `databind:foreach`

Here is the piece of code

```
      <div class="product-list">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
            <li>
                <div class="product-summary">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <a data-bind="attr:{href: Link}">
                            <img data-bind="attr:{src: SummaryImageUrl, title: DisplayName}" alt="product image" />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h4 class="product-title" data-bind="attr:{title: DisplayName}">
                            <a data-bind="attr:{href: Link}, text: DisplayName"></a>
                        </h4>
                        <!-- ko if: Brand-->
                        <div data-bind="html: Brand" class="product-brand"></div>
                        <!-- /ko-->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: Brand-->
                        <div class="product-brand">&nbsp;</div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
```

I want to show a message if there is no product.Hence, added a line as below:

```
   <div data-bind="visible:products().length==0">
        No product(s) found.
    </div>

    <div class="product-list">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
            <li>
```

Now when page is loading, it shows `No products found` and then hides it and renders whole products

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the data for the products is loaded compared to when it gets rendered on to the screen.  I imagine what is happening is that there is a process to retrieve the products from the server, while that is happening the screen is rendered and bound to the view model, resulting in the `No Products Found` being displayed.  then at some unspecified time later the products get loaded and the screen gets updated with the new data.  I think what you probably need is a flag to indicate when a search is being performed, and when its finished.  this will allow you to show and hide the rendering of the results when the results are known.

```
<div data-bind="visible: showResults">    
    <div data-bind="visible:products().length==0">
            No product(s) found.
     </div>

     <div class="product-list">
         <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
             <li></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would created an observable flag to notify if data is loaded and then wrap your html in ko virtual binding as shown in following code snippet.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.isDataLoaded = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.loadData = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      self.products.push({name:"A"});
      self.products.push({name:"B"});
      self.products.push({name:"C"});
      self.products.push({name:"D"});
      self.isDataLoaded(true);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var vm = new viewModel();
vm.loadData();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--ko if:isDataLoaded-->
<div class="product-list">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
            <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible:products().length==0">
        No product(s) found.
 </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
```